# is it possible to automatically purge a Word document of all scripts and other malicious threats?

Tags: scripting, ms-word, virus

reputedly, it is possible to make a "malicious" Word document. Maybe using embedded VB script? Anyway, not sure. My question is, is it possible to make an app that safely scrubs all such insertions from a .doc file? Of course, preferably this app should work without actually opening that file in Word application since presumably that may be sufficient for the machine to get damaged.

Is there something like that out there already? Is this even a problem worthy of discussion or in reality there is nothing really malicious that can be done using the Word documents distributed online?

ADDED LATER: johnnyArt, yes, and when you get dirt on your clothes, make sure to go to mommy and tell her about it. Mommy knows best! As a computer programmer, I am interested in learning more about how the world works, including how the world of .doc files and their embedded malicious scripts works. As for using the antivirus and anti-spyware, I will handle these issues without your precious advice. As will, probably, most other users of this forum.

Comment: No need for your harshness here, I was giving you my advice, simple as that. It's not like I'm forcing it down your throat or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should scan the file with your antivirus/spyware of choice.
My advice is, if it has malware in it, it's not worth "cleaning" it for use.
Get yourself a clean copy somewhere else.